# Is there a recipe to make a specific tier 2-3 talisman?

Tags: path-of-exile

As stated in the title, is there a recipe to make a specific tier 2-3 talisman?
I want to complete the challenge in the current season (talisman) to get some of these types of talisman.

Do I need 5 of certain types to make a specific type, or is just a random number going around?

Answer (score 1):

It's random number generator at its best. You'll have to grind.

If you will be running short of time, try buying some tier 1 or tier 2 talismans at poe.trade and use them.

Comment: Have a source for your info? if you have that is better, if dont, i will wait for another answer, thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, I did my best to look for the source and didn't find any, so my answer is based on personal experience in playing Talisman league. Also, please note that Clutching and Longtooth talismans are hardcore-only, so don't try getting them in Talisman softcore.